# select a range from multiple tables named by date

Tags: php, mysql, date, select, sphinx

The tables have the same structure and are named like (year and month attached):

```
- tb_201302
- tb_201303
- tb_201304
```

Each table has a field `date_insert` that contains the exact insert time in timestamp.

Question: I want to be able to do a selection from those multiple tables, something like (in pseudo code):

```
SELECT * FROM tb_201302, tb_201303 WHERE date_insert > '02/15' and date_insert < '03/25'
```

> '02/05' and '03/25' would be timestamps normally

So it's basically selectin a range in multiple tables.

I also tried using UNION

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT * FROM tb_201302 WHERE date_insert > '02/15' and date_insert < '03/25')
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tb_201303 WHERE date_insert > '02/15' and date_insert < '03/25')
) results
```

But I'm getting a `syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting SELECT near '(SELECT * FROM tb_201202`

Any ideas ?

Comment: Yes. Pursue the UNION option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumning this really is a **SphinxQL** question (the error message appears to be a Sphinx produced *NOT* a **MySQL** produced error)...

Your first attempt is right, just that you need to convert the actual timestamp, to be a numberic. Can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` in creating your index, so that the sphinx attribute contains  a unix timestamp.

Can then convert it to the same numeric

```
SphinxQL> SELECT * FROM tb_201302, tb_201303 
          WHERE date_insert > 1360886400 AND date_insert < 1364169600
```

(`strtotim()` in PHP can be used to get a timestamp from a date string)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM tb_201302 WHERE date_insert > '02/15' and date_insert < '03/25'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM tb_201303 WHERE date_insert > '02/15' and date_insert < '03/25'
) results
```

Try this